how to statically link to and and use libmatroska
I need to programmatically extract some .mkv metadata, and libMatroska seems perfect for doing just that.
there did not seem to be any pre-compiled libraries availabe, but the process of compiling it using cmake didn't seem too difficult, so did that (first compiling libEBML and then libMatroska) and ended up with a libmatroska.a file in addition to libebml.a, which was statically linked while building libmatroska.a, but not really sure if I need it anymore?
now, trying to statically link with this in my project, but can't seem to get the IDE to realise that matroska/FileKax.h exists, even though that directory is valid and it can see the other libMatroska header files in that same directory.
(the statement: include "matroska/FileKax.h" is grayed out in the IDE)
I'm pretty new to CMake and there is little to no documentation on how to actually use this in a project
the test project directory structure looks like:

where ebml and matroska folders contain their respective header libraries + ebml_export.h and matroska_export.h files created during compilation
the CMakeLists.txt is as follows:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(mkv_metadata_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 26)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/matroska)

set(MATROSKA_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/matroska")
set(MATROSKA_LIB_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libmatroska.a")


set(EBML_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ebml")
set(EBML_LIBRARY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libebml.a")

add_library(matroska STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(matroska PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${MATROSKA_LIB_PATH}/libmatroska.a)

add_executable(mkv_metadata_test main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(mkv_metadata_test PRIVATE matroska)

furthermore, if I open FileKax.h
/*!
  \file
  \version \$Id: FileKax.h,v 1.5 2004/04/14 23:26:17 robux4 Exp $
  \author Steve Lhomme     <robux4 @ users.sf.net>
*/
#ifndef LIBMATROSKA_FILE_H
#define LIBMATROSKA_FILE_H

//#include <vector>

#include "matroska/KaxTypes.h"
#include "ebml/IOCallback.h"
//#include "MainHeader.h"
//#include "TrackType.h"
//#include "StreamInfo.h"
//#include "Cluster.h"
//#include "CodecHeader.h"

using namespace libebml;

namespace libmatroska {

//class Track;
//class Frame;

/*!
    \class MATROSKA_DLL_API FileMatroska
    \brief General container of all the parameters and data of an Matroska file
    \todo Handle the filename and next filename
    \todo Handle the IOCallback selection/type
*/
class MATROSKA_DLL_API FileMatroska {
    public:
    FileMatroska(IOCallback & output);
    ~FileMatroska() = default;
#ifdef OLD
  filepos_t RenderHead(const std::string & aEncoderApp);
  uint32 ReadHead();
  uint32 ReadTracks();
  uint32 ReadCodec();
  void Close(const uint32 aTimeLength);

  inline void type_SetInfo(const std::string & aStr) {myMainHeader.type_SetInfo(aStr);}
  inline void type_SetAds(const std::string & aStr) {myMainHeader.type_SetAds(aStr);}
  inline void type_SetSize(const std::string & aStr) {myMainHeader.type_SetSize(aStr);}
  inline void type_SetSize(uint64 aSize) {myMainHeader.type_SetSize(aSize);}

  inline uint8 GetTrackNumber() const { return myTracks.size(); }

  void track_SetName(Track * aTrack, const std::string & aName);
  void track_SetLaced(Track * aTrack, bool bLaced = true);

  Track * CreateTrack(const track_type aType);
  inline Track * GetTrack(const uint8 aTrackNb) const
  {
      if (aTrackNb > myTracks.size())
    return NULL;
      else
    return myTracks[aTrackNb-1];
  }

  void Track_GetInfo(const Track * aTrack, TrackInfo & aTrackInfo) const;

  void Track_SetInfo_Audio(Track * aTrack, const TrackInfoAudio & aTrackInfo);
  void Track_GetInfo_Audio(const Track * aTrack, TrackInfoAudio & aTrackInfo) const;

  void Track_SetInfo_Video(Track * aTrack, const TrackInfoVideo & aTrackInfo);
  void Track_GetInfo_Video(const Track * aTrack, TrackInfoVideo & aTrackInfo) const;

  void SelectReadingTrack(Track * aTrack, bool select = true);

  /*!
      \return wether the frame has been added or not
  */
  bool AddFrame(Track * aTrack, const uint32 aTimecode, const binary *aFrame, const uint32 aFrameSize,
         bool aKeyFrame = true, bool aBFrame = false);

  /*!
      \return wether the frame has been read or not
  */
  bool ReadFrame(Track * & aTrack, uint32 & aTimecode, const binary * & aFrame, uint32 & aFrameSize,
         bool & aKeyFrame, bool & aBFrame);

  /*
      Render the pending cluster to file
  */
  void Flush();

  void SetMaxClusterSize(const uint32 value);
  void SetMinClusterSize(const uint32 value) {myMinClusterSize = value;}

    protected:
  MainHeader myMainHeader;

  std::vector<Track *> myTracks;
  std::vector<uint8> mySelectedTracks;

//  Track *findTrack(Track * aTrack) const;

  Cluster  myCurrWriteCluster; /// \todo merge with the write one ?
  uint32   myReadBlockNumber;
  Cluster  myCurrReadCluster;
  binary * myCurrReadBlock;      ///< The buffer containing the current read block
  uint32   myCurrReadBlockSize;  ///< The size of the buffer containing the current read block
  uint8    myCurrReadBlockTrack; ///< The track number of the current track to read

  uint32 myMaxClusterSize;
  uint32 myMinClusterSize;

  StreamInfo myStreamInfo;

  CodecHeader myCodecHeader;

  inline bool IsMyTrack(const Track * aTrack) const;
  inline bool IsReadingTrack(const uint8 aTrackNum) const;
#endif // OLD
  IOCallback & myFile;

};

} // namespace libmatroska

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

MATROSKA_DLL_API void matroska_init();
MATROSKA_DLL_API void matroska_done();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // FILE_KAX_HPP


the symbol FileMatroska (in \class MATROSKA_DLL_API FileMatroska) does not seem to get resolved and my main.cpp complains that KaxCuePoint is "incomplete"
